# Strange thing happens with my keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Some keys works only if other specific one is pressed. For example <kbd>S</kbd> works only if <kbd>Q</kbd> is pressed, <kbd>C</kbd> works if <kbd>D</kbd> is  pressed and <kbd>K</kbd> works if <kbd>J</kbd> is pressed, in any other scenario they dont work. Someone know solution?

Comment: Fixed it, it was misspell

Comment: Those key combinations are a mix of rows and columns of the key matrix, and oddly scattered.  Is it possible you got a little liquid splattered on the keyboard? It's possible that it's a failure in the encoding chip in the keyboard.  Unless it's an expensive keyboard, it usually isn't worth the time to try to fix it beyond blowing out crumbs and pet hair.  It's hit or miss to fix spilled liquid (even water).

Answer (score 0):

A cleaning of the keyboard will solve this problem.

Comment: Already tried that, maybe i must clear it better ?